# Controller is accepting null as request body on one environment but refuses on another

Tags: java, spring

I have encountered a puzzling behavior between production and development environments.

My Spring controller is as follows (the same between the two environments)

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/find")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<D> find(@RequestBody P params) throws Exception {
        // omitted
    }
```

When a request is done by Chrome on production environment, the browser receives correct response:

[image]

However, when the request is done by Chrome on development environment, Spring prints a warning (warning points to missing request body)

```
WARN [qtp543254421-52] AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:197 -
Resolved 
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
Required request body is missing: public java.util.List<D> 
pl.kg.ut.postgres.controller.ReadPostgresController.find(P) throws java.lang.Exception]
```

Here's a screenshot of that request from Chrome.

[image]

When we compare the two request (from dev and prod) there are some similarities and differences. Request URL, Request Method, and Request Payload are the same. (What is striking is that Request Payload is null  but the controller needs a payload.) What is different is request headers: there are more of them when request is made from production.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't GET HTTP method request with body for parsing.

Data enclosure is done with HTTP POST for stored request' body.
Please, try to defined code below for posting valid payload.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<D> find(@RequestBody P params) throws Exception {
    // omitted
}
```

Comment: You are right here but it doesn't answer my question on why it works on one env but doesn't on another.